# How can I map discriminated unions to concrete types (like classes) via a factory function in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, types, discriminated-union, static-typing, unification

I'm trying something like the following:

```js
type Node =
    | { type: 'Group'; children: Node[] }
    | { type: 'Obj'; payload: number };

class Group {
    readonly type = 'Group';
    constructor(public n: Node[]) { }
}

class Obj {
    readonly type = 'Obj';
    constructor(public p: number) { }
}

type NodeMappings =
    { Group: Group; Obj: Obj };

function createNode<T extends Node>(node: T): NodeMappings[T['type']] {
    switch (node.type) {
        case 'Group':
            return new Group(node.children); // error!
        case 'Obj':
            return new Obj(node.payload); // error!
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve something like the given code that works with all kinds of types for the mapping in the `createNode` function (here done via a `switch ... case`)? Is this a bug in Typescript?

Comment: It's considered a missing feature, not a bug, see [ms/TS#33014](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014). Right now control flow analysis (like `switch`/`case` checks) doesn't affect generic type parameters (like `T`). Until this is implemented (which *might* happen in TS5.5), the workaround is to either avoid generics or avoid control flow analysis. In your example we can refactor to control flow analysis and use generic indexing instead, as shown in [this playground link](//tsplay.dev/wReD5W). Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Wow that was fast, thanks. yes this kind of solves my issue. The only minor inconveniences I have with that (but this is a nit and doesn't really bother me that much), is that I need to cast the `node` to either of those subtypes, to pass relevant attributes to the constructors of those classes, and that it needs closures/properties (I was not able to make the "get object" a function for additional context, so that it could be extracted outside of the function).

Comment: There are ways around it that don't involve casting but I'd need a [mre] to help.  Something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoogaW) maybe?  Tell me how to proceed.

Comment: Wow, I just wanted to create an example what I was trying and you already have the solution I was aiming for, yes this is pretty much what I wanted, awesome thanks :).

Comment: But... what do you want to do with this question? Shall I answer the question as asked or do you want to [edit] to use a [mre] of your followup issue?

Comment: I wrote up an answer to what I think the new version is. Would you mind copying the code at the top of my answer into the question where it belongs?  Or do you mind if I [edit] for you?

Comment: I can do as you asked (i.e. replace my updated question with your code), it's just a minor difference I think, or do you want to update the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler cannot just see the abstract relationship between the `Node` and `NodeMappings` in order to verify that `createNode()` is properly implemented.

If you want to express that relationship in a way the compiler understands, you need to do so explicitly by following the steps laid out in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). Your need a "base" type which looks like a key-value mapping from each `type` property to the rest of the relevant `Node` member:

```
type NodeMap = { [N in Node as N['type']]:
    { [P in keyof N as P extends "type" ? never : P]: N[P] }
}
```

which is equivalent to

```
// type NodeMap = { 
//   Group: { children: Node[]; }; 
//   Obj: { payload: number; };
// }
```

And then all the operations should be represented in terms of that base type and [indexes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into that type with a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) key, or generic indexes into a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) on that type.

We can recreate `Node` as such a indexed mapped type (called a *distributive object type* in microsoft/TypeScript#47109):

```
type MyNode<K extends keyof NodeMap = keyof NodeMap> =
    { [P in K]: { type: P } & NodeMap[P] }[K]
```

and then `createNode()` is written in terms of the generic index `K` and `MyNode<K>`:

```
function createNode<K extends keyof NodeMap>(node: MyNode<K>) {
    const m: { [K in keyof NodeMappings]: (n: MyNode<K>) => NodeMappings[K] } = {
        Group(n) { return new Group(n.children) },
        Obj(n) { return new Obj(n.payload) }
    };
    return m[node.type](node); // okay
}
```

Note how we had to abandon the [control-flow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#control-flow-analysis) based implementation with `switch`/`case`. You can't just check `node.type` and expect `K` to be affected, at least until and unless [microsoft/TypeScript#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014) is implemented.   So instead of doing this, we just make an object whose methods have the same names as `node.type` and which accept the corresponding node as input.  That is, we write an object that maps `MyNode<K>` to `NodeMappings[K]`.

And this works; the call `m[node.type](node)` is effectively the same as your `switch`/`case` version, but we use property lookups to distinguish between the cases.

And let's make sure it still works for callers:

```
function test() {
    const n = createNode({ type: 'Obj', payload: 8 });
    //    ^? const n: Obj
}
```

Looks good.  `K` is inferred as `"Obj"` and thus the return type is `Obj` as expected.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.4.2#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBVATgcwBZIN4Ch8likAXATxmQDkB7AE2QF4iS2AfPMyiALiQDkAcTS0ArjAEBuJPCwBLADb00EYPzqMA2gF0kAX1ZtinXNyr8BAeQBGAK2lI45RbRD1+wMWBsQ0BqUI2ADMxYHhSeVpgWVUQUghNCAAhdwAeABUkCAAPBOB6KCQkgD4ACmAGPiQMgEoNKoBZEBgYeWAMKC0MrQEKKgEdPQJjEigAd3lSOSQKqoA6fohavCNRkngQKGRhUQkBXjX141VSMTQY4AhxpBFxGDnGebklFTVawOO2Te3BWwdDl91qdzpdrkh-o8IPNnK53B8jiRDGxDEENootkU7hJVsc4vRoopyOZmIJsZJPut4NEoKQ0GIIrQ0GUYGIbIp5PAkOpilVdCszMikWjiPAMVAiv9ccCIO5CcSlkgmH97NJEaKaXSGaQmSy2RyuTBPN5fGgBQY1qi2Iqks1Wu1Okr1VxyfxyTJ-vwpfpAmsbU0WkquFpqEh2rzGEgtsVektBjpAeszFoAAphmIAawg5FowWKUaKady+UKSAAREsy0gAPzciAANz8SH4KYTMdbFpRIpJSEa5CSaQA0tk8mpS1mc3nbYHlRPcxGIHaSk7jsm0+HB22zEsWwYkAAyBd21N6fRaTfd0LhSLRWKyhID4fFsdFOdTgMwcqVRj8PuPkoCs61LALSSBgPwybDuGb5Hi0bQdFAbYVL+-ZVEOAFKsu072gh56nkGIxArcewPMA5oghcdY3OSFTPAoyiqGRBgADTOmwkJMWYFFgjcHEwiALhuPQKxCqMPrOtxYFaN+0JLDoUIIl2IRhBEUQxAktJlIBxzAaBMTKvAcQPlUZTbjwlj-AIzFOAJcIeEgAAcBiKesAD0rlsAAerWumkNyXr2JahD6EAA)

Comment: Whoops, I think we have a race condition here ^^. I just updated the [example](https://tsplay.dev/NBd94W)
you have given, I'll read through the answer...

Comment: I mean, I *could* go back and change my code to match the new example but I'd certainly *rather* stop working on this and have you use mine.  But I'm not the only person in this exchange so it's sort of up to you.

Comment: Alright, I'll take your example

Comment: Done, thanks for that elaborative answer!